# docker mediawiki localsettings with docker run

Tags: docker, mediawiki

If I run mediawiki by docker run:

```
docker run --name wiki --link mysql -p 81:80 -d mediawiki
```

Where I have to put the **LocalSettings.php** file?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mount the settings file from the host:

```
docker run --name wiki --link mysql -p 81:80 -v /path/on/your/computer/to/LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php -d mediawiki
```

Comment: I think you are right, but unfortunately doesn't work for me, I see the following output:

Error response from daemon: Drive sharing seems blocked by a firewall.

I have the Windows Firewall down, and clicked on "Share it" when prompted by Docker...!